# ShapeLayer.strokeEnd is filling up out of time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I've created a `CAShapeLayer` as a circle, and added some animation that fills it as the image loads, until the circle is completely filled and the image is displayed.

I'm using Alamofire's `.fractionCompleted` as the value of my `shapeLayer.strokeEnd` property *(which defines the speed at which the circle fills up)*. But it has a weird behaviour; it loads completely, and then goes backwards, and then fills up entirely, and then goes back again, and so on and so forth.

Here's a GIF that explains the situation: [Click to see](https://i.gyazo.com/1705887cb09a27fae2734ea81ba18a68.mp4)

**Here's the API call:**

```
class Service {
    
    var delegate: ServiceDelegate?
    let baseUrl = "https://picsum.photos/id/0/5616/3744"
    typealias ImageCallback = (UIImage) -> Void
    
    func fetchImage(handler: @escaping ImageCallback) {
        
        AF.request(baseUrl).validate().downloadProgress { progress in
            
            let percentage = CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted)
            
            self.delegate?.sendProgress(progress: percentage)
            
        }.response { (response) in
            
            do {
                guard let data = response.data,
                      let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            
                handler(image)
            } catch {
                print("DEBUG ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Here's ServiceDelegate's func implemented on the VC:**

```
extension ViewController: ServiceDelegate {
    func sendProgress(progress: CGFloat) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.animateCircle(strokeEnd: progress)
        }
        
        print(progress)
            
    }
}
```

**The basicAnimation code:**

```
func animateCircle(strokeEnd: CGFloat) {
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.duration = 2
    basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
    
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "randomKey")
}
```

If you need another chunk of code, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it. My problem was that I was still using the animateCircle() func, even when the shapeLayer.strokeEnd was supossed to do the exact same job. When I commented the function, it worked perfectly.